# How to get through the NativeScript-Angular Lesson 2 Step 10?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to do the Playground tutorial for NativeScript and Angular. I´m stuck in lesson 2 step 10, due to a compiling error stating, that the http-related segments of the login function are not known to the class.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { User } from "./user.model";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
register(user: User) {
alert("About to register: " + user.email);
}

login(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(
        Config.apiUrl + "user/" + Config.appKey + "/login",
        JSON.stringify({
            username: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }),
        { headers: this.getCommonHeaders() }
    ).pipe(
        map(response => response.json()),
        tap(data => {
            Config.token = data._kmd.authtoken
        }),
        catchError(this.handleErrors)
    );
}
}
```

What I think is, something is not importet yet, that´s why the http-related functions don´t work.
I searched in the tutorials code, if I´ve missed something, but I can´t find anything.

I would be nice, if someone could tell me, how to continue the tutorial, or tell me were to find the needed snippet.:)

Comment: you dont have a constructor with the http class injected, it should be `constructor(private http: HttpClient){}` and `import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";`

Comment: Did you import the [NativeScriptHttpClientModule](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/http#http-get)?

Comment: NativeScriptHttpClientModule was the one to go, I found the whole solution in the end of the tutorial, but these changes were never mentioned:/

Answer (score 0):

[Check your setup](https://angular.io/guide/http)

- Confirm that the import for HttpClient is added in your module

```js
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
```

- Check that you add the `http` object to your class constructor

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

then you can refer to the `http` from any function in your class

```js
doSomePosting() {
    // this.http.post(postUrl, postData, postOptions);
}
```